# How do you make a general function in zsh to find a random file in a directory?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I created a zsh script and noticed some repitition. This caused me to try and refactor it which has brought on a headache.

The original thing I wanted to refactor looked like this:

```
MUSIC=($BASE_DIR/music/*.mp3)
cvlc --play-and-exit $MUSIC[$RANDOM%$#MUSIC+1] &
```

It's quite simple, I take a directory and find all the mp3's in it. I then select a random one to play with cvlc.

Now selecting a random file from a list seems useful so I tried to create a helper function to do that as I needed to do it twice. My first attempt looked like so:

```
random () {
        echo "$@"[$RANDOM%$#+1]
}
```

I have it echoing to just check everything and I would call this with:

```
random $MUSIC
```

Now this results in:

```
no matches found: ./music/my_last_song_in_the_list.mp3[5647%12+1]
```

I then tried several other things:

```
random () {
        #echo "$@"
        echo $1
        echo $*
        echo "$*"
        echo $@
        echo "$@"
        echo $#

        ITEMS="$@"
        NUM=$#

        echo $ITEM
        echo $NUM
        echo $#ITEMS

        echo $[$NUM+1]
        echo $ITEMS[$RANDOM%$NUM+1]

        echo "$@"[$RANDOM%$#+1]
}
```

Now the closest I got was setting `$ITEMS` to be `"$@"` (which I've assume is the best result given [this article](http://zshwiki.org/home/scripting/args), I have also tried with every other one of the collections you can see echoed above). What happens there is that I get an individual character from the name and `$#ITEMS` is the length of the entire string.

Does anyone have a solution for how to get and pass multiple arguments into a local function in a zsh script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function randomArgument {
      # -L make any option changes local to the function
      # -R all setable options are set to their default values.
      # thus using this makes sure the function will work the same way
      # regardless of their settings. Not really necessary here... but
      # good practice.
      emulate -RL zsh
      if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then return 0; fi
      local rr # local so as not to leak the variable to the shell
      # $(( )) is the way to do arithmetic in Zsh
      rr=$(( 1 + $RANDOM % $# ))
      echo $@[${rr}]
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explainations for your intention.

Comment: Yes, could you explain what the `emulate -RL zsh` line does, why `local` needed to be used. Also, I think the `rr` line should be `rr=$(($RANDOM % $# + 1))` instead of the other way round. (An explanation as to why two sets of brackets are needed would also be good). In addition, could you explain whether `$@` works better than `"$@"` in the context of [this article](http://zshwiki.org/home/scripting/args).

Comment: Addition is commutative and has lower precedence than `%`; the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Using default `zsh` settings, quoting `$@[$rr]` is unnecessary; word splitting and filename generation are not performed on parameter expansions.